# Cellular Radio in Android Phone

Tags: android, cpu-usage, telephony, phone-call, dual-sim

I am researching on Cellular connectivity in rural areas.
Is there an API in Android which helps you access Cellular radio properties as a call or SMS is made ?

**P.S.**: I am not looking for properties like signal Strength or Neighboring Cell Info. I am interested in listening to changes like in increase in CPU cycles, cellular handovers etc.

**Edit:**
My main reason for asking this is, so that I can detect events from different SIMs in Dual SIM phones as there is no current way of doing this. So by monitoring the radios, I can tell whether this was the SIM that made the call or the other.

Comment: You can detect when a call is made by granting android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in the manifest, but I'm not sure if you can access cpu data. Curious to see.

Comment: Eric, u are right dude but as you said, the Info gained from READ_PHONE_STATE is very shallow, I need to get Deeper which you interpret from from my edit now.

Comment: I don't know, I'm waiting to see who answers this.